# where clause in contentProvider's query in Android

Tags: android, where-clause

I want to add functionality of `contains()` method in where clause. Right now I was doing something like `"address = ?"` and providing address in arguments but now I want to use a logic which works as `address.contains(?)` and then providing the address in arguments. How can I implement it?
Till now my code is and need to know the require modification.

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
                "person", "date", "body", "type" };

        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                projection, "address = ?", new String[]{addressToBeSearched}, null);
```

Comment: `"address = ?"` => `"address LIKE ?"` and `addressToBeSearched` => `"%" + addressToBeSearched + "%"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                projection, "address LIKE ?", new String[]{addressToBeSearched + "%" }, null);
```

Comment: Please remove this "=" sign so that I might be able to mark your answer as answer of this question.
and thakns btw. Its all I needed.